# Entire react native app showing on lockscreen

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I have an app with the following code on the MainActivity.java:

```java
package com.MyApp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.MyApp.CustomLockscreenPackage; 

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "MyApp";
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The lines who make the app work on the lockscreen are:

```java
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        );
    }
```

But, the entire app works on the lockscreen, and i need to make only certain screens works on the lockscreen (It's a call app).
I tried creating a native module but don't worked.
i know its possible remove the flags with:

```java
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

So, if i can call these lines on my react native screen, it probably can work

[EDIT]: I made a module who does that for me: [react-native-keep-awake](https://github.com/willnaoosmit/react-native-keep-awake)

[EDIT]: How to use my module:

first of all, install him:

`npm install --save https://github.com/willnaoosmit/react-native-keep-visible`
(or with yarn, if you want to)

then:

```
import KeepAwake from 'react-native-keep-awake'; #import the module, of course

KeepAwake.activate(); #when you want to use the app on the lockscreen

KeepAwake.deactivate(); #when you dont want to use the app on the lockscreen anymore
```

Comment: How did you solve your issue using your made library ? I am facing same issue

Comment: I added it to the question.
Please upvote the question if it helped! @Harshit

Comment: It will work if i use it in fcm push notification receive method?

Comment: i dont know the context, not even what you're aiming for. but if you call `KeepAwake.activate()` it will work on the lockscreen.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help

Comment: Leave a upvote if it helped. It helps me too.

Comment: It's not working if i have activated if app is invoked by background service from killed state

Comment: here's a tutorial of how you can create a unstoppable service: https://medium.com/reactbrasil/how-to-create-an-unstoppable-service-in-react-native-using-headless-js-93656b6fd5d1

And, i see you're creating a calling app, right?
so maybe would be better suppor push notifications on your app to make it work on background/foreground

Comment: Use i have used background notification handler to receive call and i am also able to start app on push received but when device is locked or screen off then in this case screen should be turned on and also app should be shown in lock screen. This is the exact issue

Answer (score 0):

FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED is deprecated in API level 27.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
use can use
https://github.com/ShahilMangroliya/react-native-keep-awake.git
It's a fork for FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED solution